# Save multiple records with doctrine and getting id every record

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I Have a function in my php application to save data in table:

```
public function saveAdditionalDataForRecord($header, $data, $record)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
            $clientRecordAdditionalData  = new ClientRecordAdditionalData();
            $clientRecordAdditionalData->setName($value);
            $clientRecordAdditionalData->setValue($data[$key]);
            $clientRecordAdditionalData->setRecord($record);
            $em->persist($clientRecordAdditionalData);
        }
        $em->flush();
        return $clientRecordAdditionalData->getId();

    }
```

I'd like to return array with id saved records instead last saved record. How Can I do that? I would be greateful for help ;) 
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
public function saveAdditionalDataForRecord($header, $data, $record)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $ids = array();
    $objects = array();

    foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
        $clientRecordAdditionalData  = new ClientRecordAdditionalData();
        $clientRecordAdditionalData->setName($value);
        $clientRecordAdditionalData->setValue($data[$key]);
        $clientRecordAdditionalData->setRecord($record);
        $em->persist($clientRecordAdditionalData);

        $objects[] = $clientRecordAdditionalData;
    }

    $em->flush();

    foreach($objects as $object)
    {
        $ids[] = $object->id;
    }

    return $ids;

}
```

Comment: Hmm, but using  $em->flush(); for every record isn't optimal. Sometimes program can crash.

Comment: @KrzysztofMichalski Flush shouldn't be causing a program crash if it's called like that and that's a bug you should report. I've modified the answer anyway to work around the flush issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to do this: either use non-sequintial IDs (UUIDs) that you generate before inserting or retrieve last insert id after each insert(flush).

Install `ramsey/uuid` to generate uuid.

```
foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
    $clientRecordAdditionalData  = new ClientRecordAdditionalData();
    $clientRecordAdditionalData->setId(Uuid::uuid4());
    $clientRecordAdditionalData->setName($value);
    $clientRecordAdditionalData->setValue($data[$key]);
    $clientRecordAdditionalData->setRecord($record);
    $em->persist($clientRecordAdditionalData);
}
```